# Need help making button relay information

Tags: java, swing

Okay, so I have made a GUI with some input boxes and a combo box. I am wondering how I would go about having a listener know when the button is pressed then relay all the information in the imput boxes and combo box into different parts of the script...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class dogedice extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JPanel contentPane;
        private JTextField textField;
        private JComboBox combo;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        dogedice frame = new dogedice();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public dogedice() {
            setTitle("DogeDice Bot");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
            setContentPane(contentPane);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
            GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
            gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
            gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
            gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0};
            gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
            panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

            //Every new Label however needs every part that says "user" or on the Password: "pass" changed to something unique.
            JLabel userTag = new JLabel("Username:");
            GridBagConstraints gbc_userTag = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_userTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc_userTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc_userTag.gridx = 0;//Here are your x + y coords
            gbc_userTag.gridy = 0;//Adding to x moves left, adding to y moves down
            panel.add(userTag, gbc_userTag);

            //Every new textfield needs only the * part to change for it to be valid. (gbc_* =)
            textField = new JTextField();
            GridBagConstraints gbc_Username = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
            gbc_textField.gridy = 0;
            panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            JLabel startTag = new JLabel("Starting Bid:");
            GridBagConstraints gbc_startTag = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_startTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc_startTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc_startTag.gridx = 0;
            gbc_startTag.gridy = 2;
            panel.add(startTag, gbc_startTag);

            textField = new JTextField();
            GridBagConstraints gbc_StartBid = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
            gbc_textField.gridy = 2;
            panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            JLabel multTag = new JLabel("Multiplier:");
            GridBagConstraints gbc_multTag = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_multTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc_multTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc_multTag.gridx = 0;
            gbc_multTag.gridy = 3;
            panel.add(multTag, gbc_multTag);

            textField = new JTextField();
            GridBagConstraints gbc_Multiplier = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
            gbc_textField.gridy = 3;
            panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            JLabel minTag = new JLabel("Min Remaining:");
            GridBagConstraints gbc_minTag = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_minTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc_minTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc_minTag.gridx = 0;
            gbc_minTag.gridy = 4;
            panel.add(minTag, gbc_minTag);

            textField = new JTextField();
            GridBagConstraints gbc_MinRemaining = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
            gbc_textField.gridy = 4;
            panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            textField = new JTextField();
            GridBagConstraints gbc_Password = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
            gbc_textField.gridy = 1;
            panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            JLabel passTag = new JLabel("Password:");
            GridBagConstraints gbc_passTag = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_passTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc_passTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc_passTag.gridx = 0;
            gbc_passTag.gridy = 1;
            panel.add(passTag, gbc_passTag);

            textField = new JTextField();
            GridBagConstraints gbc_Odds = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
            gbc_textField.gridy = 5;
            panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            JLabel oddsTag = new JLabel("Odds %:");
            GridBagConstraints gbc_oddsTag = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_oddsTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc_oddsTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc_oddsTag.gridx = 0;
            gbc_oddsTag.gridy = 5;
            panel.add(oddsTag, gbc_oddsTag);

            textField = new JTextField();
            GridBagConstraints gbc_ComboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
            gbc_textField.gridy = 6;
            panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            //This is the Combo Box
            combo = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"BTC","LTC","PPC","NMC","XPM","FTC","ANC","DOGE","NXT"});
            combo.addActionListener(this);
            GridBagConstraints gbc_list = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_list.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc_list.gridx = 1;
            gbc_list.gridy = 7;
            panel.add(combo, gbc_list);

            JLabel maxTag = new JLabel("MaxBet:");
            GridBagConstraints gbc_maxTag = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_maxTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc_maxTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc_maxTag.gridx = 0;
            gbc_maxTag.gridy = 6;
            panel.add(maxTag, gbc_maxTag);

            JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
            contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5));

            JButton btnConfirm = new JButton("Turn Up");
            panel_1.add(btnConfirm);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Current Balance");
            textArea.setColumns(1);
            scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

        JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane();//This will hold the information the bot sends over such as win/loose or error
            contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            JTextArea textAreal = new JTextArea("Input bot information here...");
            textArea.setColumns(20);
            scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

            pack();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == combo) {
                System.out.println(combo.getSelectedIndex()+1);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite straightforward to add an `ActionListener` to a `JButton`.

```
// ...
btnConfirm = new JButton("Turn Up");
btnConfirm.addActionListener(this);
panel_1.add(btnConfirm);
// ...
```

Because you'll want to know when the button is triggering the callback, like so:

```
private JButton btnConfirm;
```

This way, you'll be able to tell when it's that button that triggered the actionListener() method:

```
if (event.getSource() == btnConfirm) {
    // Handle "Turn Up" button press here
}
```

Comment: *"Because you'll want to know when the button is triggering the callback"* - That's not entirely true, since at least Java 6, maybe earlier, the buttons text has been used as the action command for the `ActionEvent` if the action command isn't set.  So technically, you could simply use `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` and not need the reference to the button at all, allowing you to specify the same action in a number places, like menu items, buttons and key bindings

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Essentially you need to register an `ActionListener` with your button...

There are a number of ways you might be able to achieve this...

### You Could

Use the more traditional, purpose class...

```
public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if ("Turn Up".evt.getActionCommand()) {
            // Handle Turn Up...
        }
    }
}
```

In this context, you'll be required to provide a reference to the component you want to modify so that the `ActionHandler` can interact with it, personally, this is best done via an `interface`, but that's just me...

```
public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {
    private dogedice dice;
    public ActionHandler(dogedice dice) {
        this.dice = dice;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //...
    }
}
```

The benefit of this is you can plug an play the action handler, changing what the action does depending on your needs. If you use an `interface` instead of an implementation reference, you further decouple the action from the program

### You Could

Use use an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

```
btnConfirm = new JButton("Turn Up");
btnConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // handle turn up action...
    }
});
```

The benefit to this is, you don't end up with "another" class, the `ActionListener` can reference all the internal fields of the parent class and, because you've attached it directly, you can assume that the only thing that is going to generate the `ActionEvent` is the `btnConfirm` button.

The downside is you lose the flexibility to change how the action is handled without physically modifying the code

### You Could

Take advantage of the [`Action`s API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), this is a little like the first option, in that you (should normally) create another class specifically designed to handle the "Turn Up" event, but these are self contained entities.  That is, they carry all the information required to configure the UI element and perform the required action when triggered.

This is really good where the action may be repeated in the UI via menus, buttons or key strokes